# Unable to start kafka with zookeeper (kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Below the steps I did to get this issue :

1. Launch ZooKeeper
2. Launch Kafka : `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`

And at the second step the error happens :

> ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
>   (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: **The Cluster ID
>   Reu8ClK3TTywPiNLIQIm1w doesn't match stored clusterId
>   Some(BaPSk1bCSsKFxQQ4717R6Q) in meta.properties. The broker is trying
>   to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.**
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:220)
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
>           at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
>           at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

When I trigger `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties` **zookeeper** console returns :

> INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@216] - Creating new log file: log.1

How to fix this issue to get kafka running ?

**Edit** You can access to the proper issue on the right site (serverfault) [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/997762/unable-to-start-kafka-with-zookeeper-kafka-common-inconsistentclusteridexceptio)

**Edit Here is the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832914/11167163)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592518/kafka-broker-doesnt-find-cluster-id-and-creates-new-one-after-docker-restart/60093334#60093334

Comment: Voting to reopen in order to close for the right reason, since: [1] The question is clearly a duplicate of [Kafka Broker doesn't find cluster id and creates new one after docker restart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59592518/2985643), as noted by the OP. [2] The current reason for closing is invalid since the question is not about _"professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration"_ at all; it is about a Kafka exception on startup. (And if this question really was off topic then thousands of other questions tagged `Kafka` on SO would be as well.)

Comment: @skomisa this issue is slightly différent than the other one since it doesn’t use docker. And please also note that my issue was posted before the issue you are talking about ...

Comment: @Dorian: I'm really confused now!... You have updated this question and **linked to an another answer written by yourself as the solution**! If you are now claiming that it is not a solution then delete the text "Edit Here is the Answer" from your question above.

Comment: @skomisa yes because I wasn’t allowed to ask to re open until today... ans I wanted to share with the community how I did solve my issue ...

Comment: @Dorian Well your question got reopened! Do you care to post an answer to it now?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I managed to Solve this issue with the following steps :

1. Just Delete all the log/Data file created (or generated) into
   zookeeper and kafka.
2. Run Zookeper
3. Run Kafka

[Since this post is open again I post my answer there so you got all on the same post]

Comment: After you deleted all the log files (including its directory I assume) didn't kafka prompt you it couldn't find logs/logs.log file?

Comment: @Guy_g23 You need to run zookeper first then kafka.

Answer (score 43):

** 1. The easiest solution is to remove all kafka logs and start again.
This is enough to solve the problem. e.g.

`rm -f /tmp/kafka-logs/*`

** 2. How to find Kafka log path:**

- Open server server.properties file which is located in your kafka folder kafka_2.11-2.4.0\config\server.properties (considering your version of kafka, folder name could be kafka_<kafka_version>):
- Then search for entry log.dirs to check where logs locate
  `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs`

** 3. Why: the root cause is Kafka saved failed cluster ID in meta.properties.**

Try to delete kafka-logs/meta.properties from your tmp folder, which is located in C:/tmp folder by default on windows, and /tmp/kafka-logs on Linux

if kafka is running in docker containers, the log path may be specified by volume config in the docker-compose - see [docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes)   -- Chris Halcrow

Comment: if you need to know where your log directory is at first, look at:
 <your-kafka-install-directory>/config/server.properties
and search for the 
log.dirs=.. 
row.

Comment: Note that if kafka is running in docker containers, the log path may be specified by volume config in the docker-compose - see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes

Comment: In my case, this solved the problem: `rm -f /tmp/kafka-logs/*`

Comment: Or we can just locate the file and delete it wherever it is

`locate kafka-logs/meta.properties`

gives you 
<path>/kafka-logs/meta.properties

and then

`rm <path>/kafka-logs/meta.properties`

Answer (score 22):

For mac, the following steps are needed.

- Stop kafka service: `brew services stop kafka`
- open kafka *server.properties* file: `vim /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties`
- find value of *log.dirs* in this file. For me, it is `/usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs`
- delete `path-to-log.dirs/meta.properties` file
- start kafka service `brew services start kafka`

Answer (score 16):

No need to delete the log/data files on Kafka. Check the Kafka error logs and find the new cluster id. Update the meta.properties file with cluster-ID then restart the Kafka.

```
/home/kafka/logs/meta.properties
```

**To resolve this issue permanently follow below.**

Check your zookeeper.properties file and look for `dataDir`path and change the path `tmp` location to any other location which should not be removed after server restart.

```
/home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

Copy the zookeeper folder and file to the new(below or non tmp) location then restart the zookeeper and Kafka.

```
cp -r /tmp/zookeeper /home/kafka/zookeeper
```

Now server restart won’t affect the Kafka startup.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Embedded Kafka with Testcontainers in your Java project like myself, then simply delete your `build/kafka` folder and Bob's your uncle.

The mentioned `meta.properties` can be found under `build/kafka/out/embedded-kafka`.

Answer (score 2):

I had some old volumes lingering around. I checked the volumes like this:

```
docker volume list
```

And pruned old volumes:

```
 docker volume prune
```

And also removed the ones that were kafka:
example:

```
docker volume rm test_kafka
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the following directories :-

a.) logs directory from kafka-server's configured location i.e. log.dir property path.

b.) tmp directory from kafka broker's location.

`log.dirs=../tmp/kafka-logs-1`

Answer (score 1):

I was using **docker-compose** to re-set up Kafka on a Linux server, with a known, working docker-compose.config that sets up a number of Kafka components (broker, zookeeper, connect, rest proxy), and I was getting the issue described in the OP. I fixed this for my ***dev server instance*** by doing the following

- `docker-compose down`
- backup `kafka-logs` directory using `cp kafka-logs -r kafka-logs-bak`
- delete the `kafka-logs/meta.properties` file
- `docker-compose up -d`

**Note for users of docker-compose**:

My log files *weren't* in the default location (`/tmp/kafka-logs`). If you're running Kafka in Docker containers, the log path can be specified by volume config in the docker-compose e.g.

```
volumes:
      - ./kafka-logs:/tmp/kafka-logs
```

This is specifying SOURCE:TARGET. `./kafka-logs` is the source (i.e. a directory named `kafka-logs`, in the same directory as the docker-compose file). This is then targeted to `/tmp/kafka-logs` as the mounted volume *within the kafka container*). So the logs can either be deleted from the source folder on the host machine, or by deleting them from the mounted volume after doing a `docker exec` into the kafka container.

see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes

Comment: This made the cluster eventually start but the existing topics data didn't load properly, so I lost all the topics

Answer (score 1):

For me, meta.properties was in  /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs
By removing it, the kafka started working.

Answer (score 0):

I also deleted all the content of the folder containing all data generated by Kafka. I could find the folder in my `.yml` file:

```
 kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.0
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - default
```

Under `volumes:` stays the location. So, in my case I deleted all files of the `data` folder located under `kafka-data`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried deleting the meta.properties file but didn't work.

In my case, it's solved by deleting legacy docker images.

But the problem with this is that deletes all previous data.
So be careful if you want to keep the old data this is not the right solution for you.

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f 'status=exited')
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on my Windows environment and had the same issue tried deleting logs from
*C:/tmp/logs*
and restarted , still failed

Then tried to manually match the cluster ID and it worked although I don't know if its safe or not but once you locate meta.properties somewhere in kafka directory you can replace the cluster ID to match with the kafka server then you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Error

```
 ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID xE_GQIvjRqOtq2SsAn0Ghw doesn't match stored clusterId Some(6RVi4Sz4QuyXQyfJym83TQ) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:218)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2024-02-14 14:40:26,552] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

And findout the `log.dirs` location

```
 grep -irn "log.dirs" /usr/odp/3.2.2.0-1/kafka/conf/

Response
/usr/odp/3.2.2.0-1/kafka/conf/server.properties:40:log.dirs=/kafka-logs
```

Go to this location edit the `meta.properties` file with valid cluster id

```
[root@nonkrb2 kafka]# cat /kafka-logs/meta.properties
#
#Wed Feb 14 14:42:22 IST 2024
cluster.id=6RVi4Sz4QuyXQyfJym83TQ
version=0
broker.id=1001
```

Restart the Kafka Broker, should work.