# Mismatch clusterid when trying to create persistent Kafka and Zookeeper docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, persistent-volumes

I am using Kafka and Zookeeper in my docker environment with the images `confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2` and `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2`. I tried to make the Kafka data persistent by adding to my docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  kafka:
    ...
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
  zookeeper:
    ...
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
```

but then I get the error

```bash
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. 
Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer) kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: 
The Cluster ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx doesn't match stored clusterId Some(XXXXXXXXXXXX) in meta.properties. 
The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. 
Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
```

According to the accepted answer in this question:
[Kafka Broker doesn't find cluster id and creates new one after docker restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592518/kafka-broker-doesnt-find-cluster-id-and-creates-new-one-after-docker-restart)

Adding volumes for the zookeeper data worked then, but not in my case. I have trouble finding the meta.properties file also. I have tried to also add volumes for the kafka/zookeeper logs, as well as configuration files under `/etc/kafka`. But the error is always is the same.

My knowledge of kafka and zookeeper is very limited, so apologies if I missed something obvious, and thanks for the help!